# Is $(-3n,3n)$ a subcover of $(-n,n)$?

Tags: general-topology

I read this: Let $C=\{(-n,n):n \in \mathbb N\}$ and $C'=\{(-3n,3n):n \in \mathbb N\}$.

Then $C$ and $C'$ are open covers of $\mathbb R$ (understood) and $C'$ is subcover of $C$ (not understood).

A subcover should be a subset of the cover. So $C$ should be a subcover of $C'$ (which means I found a typo) or I am missing something here.

Can anyone confirm this ?

Comment: $C'$ is a subcover of $C$, because any set in $C'$ is a set in $C$, but $C$ is not a subcover of $C'$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $3\mathbb N = \{3, 6, 9, \ldots\} \subset \mathbb N$ so the intervals $(-3n, 3n)$ are also of the form $(-m, m)$ with $m\in\mathbb N$. This implies that every set in $C'$ is also an element of $C$

Comment: I was thinking 3n is thrice as big as n .. but it should be C={1,2,3,4,5,6,..} and C'={3,6,9,...} and hence, C' is a subset of C. Right ?

Comment: @square_one The notation isn't correct, but the thoughts are:
$$C = \{(-1,1), (-2,2), \ldots\}; C' = \{(-3, 3), (-6, 6), \ldots\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Any set in $C'$ is in $C$: simply let $A \in C'$, take $n$ such that $A=(-3n,3n)$. Now take $m=3n$ to see that $(-m,m) \in C$. So $C' \subset C$.